# Pointer to a 2D array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have a 2D array (`int s[4][2]`)and I created a pointer as `int (*p)[2]`.

The pointer `p` is now assigned the address of 1st element of row within a for loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i<4; i++)
p = &s[i];
```

Now when I try to write the array elements data using dereferencing, I get wrong values.

```
printf ("%d \n", *p)
```

However, if I create another pointer and link that with the previous pointer

```
int *ptr = p;
```

and dereference pointer `ptr` I get correct values.

```
printf ("%d \n", *ptr)
```

When both the pointers are pointing to the same address why does one pointer (`*ptr`) work as expected and other (`*p`) does not return expected values?

Comment: Could you give a code example?

Comment: What is the type of `*p`?

Comment: Please edit your question and modify your question. Attach your code there and not in comments.

Answer (score 8):

If `p` is a pointer to array then `*p` is *array* of 2 ints (`int[2]`). So, you can't print an array element like this:

```
 printf ("%d \n", *p);
```

To print the array elements through the pointer `p`, you need to do:

```
 printf ("%d \n", (*p)[0]); /* first element */
 printf ("%d \n", (*p)[1]); /* second element */
```

Answer (score 2):

`p` is not a pointer to an `int`.  It is a pointer to an array of two `int`.  Therefore `*p` is also an array of two `int`.   Since it is not an `int`, printing it using `%d` gives undefined behaviour.

You would not be able to "link" `ptr` to `p` because of a type mismatch (`ptr` is a pointer to `int`, and `p` (as already noted) is a pointer to an array of two `int`.  Hence the assignment `ptr = p` would not compile.   If you are forcing it to compile (e.g. `ptr = (int *)p`), then `ptr` and `p` will have the same value (i.e. they will identify the same location in memory) but different type (i.e. dereferencing them interprets the contents of that memory differently).

The value (ignoring type) of `p` will be the address of `s[0][0]`.  Similarly, the value of `ptr` will be the address of `s[0][0]`.

As a result `printf("%d\n", *ptr)` will print the value of `s[0][0]`.

Answer (score 2):

> When both the pointers are pointing to the same address why does one pointer (*ptr) work as expected and other (*p) does not return expected values?

- `*p` evaluates to an `int[2]`, an array.

  Passing an `int[2]`, an array to a function, results in passing a pointer the array's 1<sup>st</sup> element, a `int*`.
- `*ptr` evaluates to an `int`.

  Passing an `int` to a function, results in passing an `int` to a function ... :-)

Answer (score 1):

By

```
int (*ptr)[2] ; // means int[2]<-(*ptr)
```

You got pointer to an array of two integers

> The pointer p is now assigned the address of 1st element of row 
>   within a for loop.

This is not correct, technically p is assigned the address of the entire `int[2]` block (Hint : use `sizeof` to verify the size).

> What is the problem with `printf ("%d \n", *ptr)`

`*ptr` by itself  doesn't contain a integer but it holds the address of the first element of `int[2]` ie `*ptr` itself is a pointer.

A working example would be

```
int main(void)
{
int i;
int s[4][2]={{0,1},{2,3},{4,5},{6,7}};
int (*ptr)[2];
for(i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    ptr=&s[i];
    printf("i:%d\n",i);
    printf("Element 1 : %d\n",(*ptr)[0]);
    printf("Element 2 : %d\n",(*ptr)[1]);
    /* Replacing (*ptr)[1] with *((*ptr)+1) gives you the same
     * results
     */
}

return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
i:0
Element 1 : 0
Element 2 : 1
i:1
Element 1 : 2
Element 2 : 3
i:2
Element 1 : 4
Element 2 : 5
i:3
Element 1 : 6
Element 2 : 7
```